# Create PM2 Ecosystem File from current processes

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu, pm2

I'm running a few programs (NodeJS and python) in my server (Ubuntu 20.04). I use PM2 CLI to create and manage processes. Now I want to manage all process through an echo system file. But when I run `pm2 ecosystem`, it just creates a sample file. I want to save my CURRENT PROCESSES to the echo system file and modify it. Anyone know how to save pm2 current process as echo system file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `pm2 startup` pm2 creates a file named `~/.pm2/dump.pm2` with all running processes (with too many parameters, as it saves the whole environment in the file)

Edit:
This file is similar to the output of the command `pm2 prettylist`

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. I used `pm2 prettylist >> pm2_list.json`